# Do events work if raised asynchronously?

Tags: c#, events, asynchronous, thread-safety

I have the following skeleton of a class. As you can see in the TODO: comment I will be implementing an AsyncEnumerator construct here. This method will grab a request and pass the data off to another method to be proccessed. Based on the process I would like to call the events, either SendMilestoneReached or SendFailed. I am worried these may happen on a different thread due to the AsyncEnumerator.

Will this have an effect on the UI thread where the Webtext class will be called?

```
/// <summary>
/// Sends Webtexts.
/// </summary>
public class Webtext
{
    #region Event Definitions

    // Events.
    public event EventHandler<SendingEventArgs> SendStarted = delegate { };
    public event EventHandler<SendingEventArgs> SendFailed = delegate { };
    public event EventHandler<SendingEventArgs> SendSuccessful = delegate { };
    public event EventHandler<SendingEventArgs> SendMilestoneReached = delegate { };

    // Shared EventArgs Object, Consumed by the Events.
    SendingEventArgs EventArgs = new SendingEventArgs();

    #endregion

    /// <summary>
    /// Executes the send request.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="Operator">The operator whos service to use.</param>
    /// <param name="Username">The username of the requested operator.</param>
    /// <param name="Password">The password of the requested operator.</param>
    /// <param name="Content">The content to send.</param>
    /// <param name="Recipient">The recipient to recieve the content.</param>
    public void ExecuteSendRequest(string Operator, 
                                   string Username, 
                                   string Password, 
                                   string Content, 
                                   string Recipient)
    {
        //TODO: Implement Async requests here.
    }

    #region Event Handlers

    /// <summary>
    /// Called when [sending started].
    /// </summary>
    protected void OnSendingStarted()
    {
        SendStarted(this, EventArgs);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Called when [send fail].
    /// </summary>
    protected void OnSendFail()
    {
        SendFailed(this, EventArgs);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Called when [send successful].
    /// </summary>
    protected void OnSendSuccessful()
    {

        SendSuccessful(this, EventArgs);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Called when [send milestone reached].
    /// </summary>
    protected void OnSendMilestoneReached()
    {
        SendMilestoneReached(this, EventArgs);
    }

    #endregion


}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Event is created by the same `Thread` that has raised it. This principle sounds simple but important to know.

So:

**Scenario 1** App is opened. `Webtext` is initialised by the form in the UI thread and its send is called. `Webtext` sends the request **synchronously** and fires the event. During the whole time, all operation is done on the UI thread.

**Scenario 2** App is opened. `Webtext` is initialised by the form in the UI thread and its send is called. `Webtext` sends the request **Asynchronously** using a worker thread. Second thread fires the event when it is finished. This will be the worker thread  (background or foreground depending on the how you create the thread). Any call through this thread to UI elements needs to be done using `Invoke`.

As you can see, **it very much depends on how you implement the send method.** I cannot see any implementation of the send itself so all I can say is if you spawn a thread or use threadpool it will be on the worker thread otherwise simply sending synchronously will be on UI thread.

Comment: Although I do not have the implementation included I think your second scenario is the one which is applicable. Essentially I will be using a webrequest object and calling it asynchronously. It is handled by a third party library which allows me to write the call sequencially but it still fires on another thread. Do you have a link on how to use invoke to fire the event back to the UI thread.

Comment: You can google for it by "Invoke UI Thread  C#". This one is very short and simple: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2004/03/17/91685.aspx

Comment: I was thinking this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1698889/raise-events-in-net-on-the-main-ui-thread as it seems a bit more dynamic.

Comment: Yes. That is better/more elegant but the basis is just the same.

Answer (score 3):

Note that if you're raising events asynchronously and the handlers need to update the user interface, they'll need to synchronize with the UI thread in order to update any user controls.  If you raise events asynchronously, you're placing a larger burden on classes that subscribe to your events:  they have to know how to do the UI thread synchronization.

For me, *in general*, I've found that asynchronous events aren't worth the trouble because almost invariably I end up having to handle those events in UI programs.  I came to the conclusion that if I want events handled asynchronously, then the handler should take care of that.

This isn't a hard and fast rule.  Not by any means.  For example, `System.Timers.Timer` raises the event on a ThreadPool thread by default, but you can specify a `SynchronizingObject` so that it can synchronize with the UI thread.

If you decide to go with asynchronous events, then I suggest that you include a facility such as the Timer's `SynchronizingObject` so that UI clients can use your class without having to muck around with the complexities of UI thread synchronization.

Comment: I don't have a choice, I am working with WP7 so most of the calls my application needs are asynchronous.

Comment: How would I go about synchronising the threads I was just going to use. Dispatcher.BeginInvoke( () => {
 // This code is on the UI thread.
}); Since alot of the fancy options in my above link wont work with wp7